# NoSuchMethodError for gRPC protobuf

Tags: java, grpc

I have to request data by `grpc`, by but when I call the grpc service, I get such error.
But it's mostly serialization calls from protobuf to java-object. Maybe someone has come across this and can tell me how I can fix this error?

```java
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$Builder.parseUnknownField(com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream, com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite, int)'
    at newbuilding.Relevance$Builder.mergeFrom(Relevance.java:398)
    at newbuilding.Relevance$1.parsePartialFrom(Relevance.java:532)
    at newbuilding.Relevance$1.parsePartialFrom(Relevance.java:524)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:889)
    at newbuilding.NewBuilding$Builder.mergeFrom(NewBuilding.java:1924)
    at newbuilding.NewBuilding$Builder.mergeFrom(NewBuilding.java:1298)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:872)
    at newbuilding.api.NewBuildingRecord$Builder.mergeFrom(NewBuildingRecord.java:449)
    at newbuilding.api.NewBuildingRecord$1.parsePartialFrom(NewBuildingRecord.java:714)
    at newbuilding.api.NewBuildingRecord$1.parsePartialFrom(NewBuildingRecord.java:706)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:889)
    at newbuilding.api.NewBuildingList$Builder.mergeFrom(NewBuildingList.java:478)
    at newbuilding.api.NewBuildingList$Builder.mergeFrom(NewBuildingList.java:289)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:872)
    at newbuilding.api.ListNewBuildingsResponse$Builder.mergeFrom(ListNewBuildingsResponse.java:595)
    at newbuilding.api.ListNewBuildingsResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(ListNewBuildingsResponse.java:885)
    at newbuilding.api.ListNewBuildingsResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(ListNewBuildingsResponse.java:877)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:86)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:48)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$MessageMarshaller.parseFrom(ProtoLiteUtils.java:223)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$MessageMarshaller.parse(ProtoLiteUtils.java:215)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$MessageMarshaller.parse(ProtoLiteUtils.java:118)
    at io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.parseResponse(MethodDescriptor.java:284)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:661)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:646)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$ThreadlessExecutor.waitAndDrain(ClientCalls.java:741)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:149)
    at newbuilding.api.NewBuildingServiceGrpc$NewBuildingServiceBlockingStub.list(NewBuildingServiceGrpc.java:436)
```

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10695#issuecomment-1267493171) explains it (i.e. using an older runtime)?

Comment: I assume this is a version mismatch. Probably you are using a newer generated code with old runtime.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution that helps me:

```
implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.22.2")
```

I have just taken the latest version and it solved my problem